# Configure Mysql with Liferay 7?

Tags: mysql, liferay-7

I am trying to configure mysql 8.0.3 database for liferay 7.I am getting this error while configuring db.

> 08:10:26,259 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-3][PoolBase:429] **HikariPool-5 -
>   Failed to execute isValid() for connection, configure connection test
>   query (null).** 24-Oct-2017 08:10:26.260 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [Main Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause 
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:422)
>     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:393)
>     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:351)
>     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:196)
>     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:442)
>     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:505)
>     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:113)

this is not complete stack trace please let me if full stack trace is required.

Comment: MySql 6.3? Are you sure?

Comment: sorry @FabFuerste i corrected the version now

Comment: Liferay 7 has been tested with MySQL 5.6 and 5.7. When do you expect MySQL 8.0.3 to be released and where did you get that super-early-access-version? ;)

Comment: He have installed the Preview release (8.0.3 rc), not the Stable release (  
5.7.20)

Comment: Liferay has been tested for 5.7, not quite, just with the old driver... if you start using new drivers it will not work imitatively. I would suggest changing your MySQL driver to a newer one. just as a note, some jars have both, new and old drivers. Example of what could happen: https://www.e-systems.tech/web/guest/blog/-/blogs/liferay-with-mysql-5-7-driver-changes

Comment: @OlafKock ya Roizpi is right i just installed a latest one i did not check much.Thanks for the support

Comment: @Roizpi Thanks for clarification

Comment: No problem. I checked the info thanks to @Olaf Kock 's message. Credits for him :).